# cannot find 'instancing' in object properties of metaball

Tags: metaballs

[image]

Hi

I'm practicing geometry node in blender 3.0.

I was trying to scatter metaball on cube.
However, I cannot find instancing menu in object properties.

Is it removed in blender 3.0?

Comment: You need to access the instancing panel on the instancer  (ie the cube), not the instanced object

Comment: The option has been removed for metaballs in Blender 3.0. Have a look here to make metaballs work with geometry nodes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245991/is-there-any-way-to-work-with-metaballs-via-geonodes