# Is there any way to work with metaballs via geonodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, metaballs

Is there any way to work with metaballs via geonodes?
I know that it was possible to at least use them as instances prior 3.0, now I cant figure out how to even this, nodes have changed

Answer (score 5):

Yes with regular instancing(Parented instancing on vertices) + Geometry nodes
it is possible.

[image]

Comment: but does it render?